# Symfony class no field or association

Tags: php, symfony

- I've added a new column in my database for my contact table called
  `added_date`
- added this column to my contact entity class `Acme\Entity\Contact` `$added_date`
- added get-setters called `getAddedDate()` and `setAddedDate()`

  ```
  class Contact {

      private $added_date;

      public function __construct()
      {
          $this->added_date = new \DateTime();
      }

      public function getAddedDate()
      {
          return $this->added_date;
      }

      public function setAddedDate($added_date)
      {
          $this->added_date = $added_date;
          return $this;
      }
  }
  ```

in my database I have the contact class with a column called `added_date` and it's type is `DATETIME`

When I run a DQL query like this:
`SELECT c.added_date FROM Acme\Entity\Contact c
WHERE c.id = :id`

I get `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 26 near 'added_date FROM': Error: Class Acme\Entity\Contact has no field or association named added_date`

Comment: What if you try `SELECT c.addedDate ...`?

Comment: can you post the entity ORM definition? yml/annotation?

Comment: @Matteo thanks Matteo for bringing that up, that was the problem

Comment: Hi @AngeloA how we can close your answer? You will post the solution and mark the question as resolved or i post an answer that suggest to inspect the Doctrine ORM files definition?

Comment: @Matteo i can close this in 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Suggested by matteo, I needed to check my doctrine ORM file for my entity. Which, in my case, was located at Resources/config/doctrine/.orm.yml

The column needed to be added there as well.

```
Acme\Entity\Contact:
    ...
    fields:
        ...
        added_date:
            type:datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following annotation above the field declaration:

```
/** @ORM\Column(type="datetime") */
private $added_date;
```

Also make sure you are importing Doctrine at the top of the class, i.e.:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
```

More options and info is listed on the relevant [Doctrine manual page](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html).

Comment: this is indeed true if you use doctrine annotations.